# How to place my logo on my map without white fields?

Tags: image, picturebox, gmap.net

I have a problem with the my picturebox.
I want to place it on my map which i got in my program. 
That works when i put my img in a Picturebox and then BringToFront();

i wanted to add a picture with the problem, but i just started at StackOverflow and doesnt have enough reputation yet... :(

Anyway my img got displayed but with the white fields around it. The img I use doenst have these white stuff around it. 
How can i make my Picturebox transparent so that the white fields get removed.

```
        LogoBox.Location = new Point(size.Width - 340, size.Height - 100);
        LogoBox.Image = Properties.Resources.Troepoet;
        LogoBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(250, 40);
        LogoBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        LogoBox.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

I tried to do it with only drawing a bitmap aswell but then i cant see any possibility to place it on the map. The map is a 'dominant' control.

Any help/suggestions?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put a picturebox on the map to draw your logo.

The easy way is to override the Map **OnPainOverlays**() and draw whatever you want (Logo, Text, any shape) on the map or another way if you don't want to inherit the GmapControl and work with the **GMapControl** by drag & drop it over a form to handle the **Paint**() Event:

```
Private Sub GMapControl1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles GMapControl1.Paint
    Dim logo As Image = image.FromFile("C:\transparentLogo.png")
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(logo, GMapControl1.Width - logo.Width - 5, 5, logo.Width, logo.Height)
End Sub
```

Make sure you make image transparent and save it as PNG format.